# How to get distinct result in mysql?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I want to find all files which **are common based on v_id**

I have three tables

```
     detail

    ----------------------------
    |d_id    |v_id    |d_name
    |--------|--------|---------
    |1       |1       |detail_A
    |2       |1       |detail_B
    |3       |2       |detail_C

    file

    --------------------
    |f_id     |fname
    |---------|---------
    |1        | file_W
    |2        | file_X
    |3        | file_Y
    |4        | file_Z

    mapping

    ---------------------------------
    |m_id   | v_id    |d_id    |f_id
    |-------|---------|--------|-----
    |1      | 1       |1       |1
    |2      | 1       |1       |2
    |3      | 1       |2       |1
    |4      | 1       |2       |3
    |5      | 2       |3       |2
    |6      | 2       |3       |4
```

the query I tried is below

```
SELECT f.f_id, f.fname
FROM mapping AS m
INNER JOIN detail AS d ON d.d_id=m.d_id
INNER JOIN file AS f ON m.f_id=f.f_id
WHERE m.v_id IN ('1','2')
GROUP BY m.f_id
HAVING COUNT(m.f_id) >=2
```

I want result as file_X as my objective is to find common file based on v_id
but using above query I am getting file_X,file_W

**expected output**

```
-----------
|f_id |fname
------|---
|2    |file_X
```

Comment: Add your expected output (as per the given sample data) in tabular format to the question

Comment: Your data appears to not be normalized.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Can you explain how it should be?

Comment: Two of your tables maintain relationships between `d_id` and `v_id`.  Ideally, only a single mapping table should be keeping track of this.

Comment: there are more data and content in detail table like `d_name` and other columns that I have not displayed here...that will be duplicate in mapping table...that's the reason I have kept it separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply count the unique value of `v_id`. So if there are two `v_id` values; in order to find the files which are available to both the `v_id` values, you can count their unique occurrences, and it should be 2.

Also, if `v_id` is integer, you can use `IN (1,2)` instead of `IN ('1', '2')`. Try:

```
SELECT f.f_id, f.fname
FROM mapping AS m
INNER JOIN detail AS d ON d.d_id=m.d_id
INNER JOIN file AS f ON m.f_id=f.f_id
WHERE m.v_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY m.f_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.v_id) = 2
```

Comment: It is integer in my database.

Comment: @NishitKotak check the updated answer, Dont use `('1', '2')`.